# diff to store only file name in another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

I want to apply diff to compare to directory recursively and store it output in `c.txt` \n
when I use `diff -qr dir1 dir2 >c.txt` It store something like `Files dir1/a.txt and dir2/a.txt differ`. But I want to store only `a` in it. Any suggestion

Comment: Read `man diff`. You can control output format. Or pipe (`|`) it through a filter to extract what you want, which is not clear from your question.

Comment: yes but how to use pipe

Comment: I don't want to use loop to check every file and store coressponding file name

Comment: Even with single `diff command` you need a loop to process output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to compare only files with the same name. `diff` exits with code `1` if files are different and with `0` otherwise.

```
for f in dir1/*
do
    b = `basename $f`
    [[ -f dir2/$b ]] && [[ diff -q $f dir2/$b ]] && echo $b >> c.txt
done
```

It's easier than to process `diff` output.

Comment: If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the problems it contains.